# FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout and LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, fragmenttransaction

While replacing the Fragments in an activity, we define a `FrameLayout` in our `activity.xml` and dynamically replace the fragments using the `FrameLayout`. What are the advantages of using `FrameLayout` over the other two layouts (`RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Framelayout is basically used to show one view on the screen. Its like layering up your views to the user. So [Framelayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) blocks the area of the screen to display a single item. and you can easily show your fragments there.

You can achieve the same using different layouts but the use of [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) is more to proper formatting of the data to be shown which can lead to the change in the screen area where you are showing your fragments.